# Is it possible to pass components as properties and add interactions to them?

Tags: reactjs

I am having the following class, that is supposed to handle a modal

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      this.confirmBtn = props.confirmBtn || <button type="button">Confirm</button>
      this.cancelBtn = props.confirmBtn || <button type="button">Cancel</button>
   }

   render(){
       return (<div>
       {this.props.children}

       <div>{this.confirmBtn} {this.cancelBtn}</div>
       </div>);

   }
}
```

Since these buttons are components, they can do whatever they were supposed to do, but what I want to do is add the extra functionality of closing the modal.

Ideally I would like something like this:

**Pseudocode**

```
render(){
   const ConfirmBtn = this.props.confirm;
   const CancelBtn = this.props.cancel;
   return (<div>
       {this.props.children}

       <div>
          <ConfirmBtn onClick={this.close.bind(this)}/> 
          <CancelBtn onClick={this.close.bind(this)}/>
       </div>);
}
```

I know it is possible to just keep the buttons internally and add callbacks to them, but I'm just wondering if this thing is even possible to do in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will work fine, assuming that `this.props.confirm` and `this.props.cancel` are *components* and not *elements*.  As an example, `Modal` would be a component but `<Modal/>` is an element.

That said, I'm not personally a fan of passing components in this way.  While it will work, you're not imposing any forced constraints on which kinds of Component is allowed to be passed in for `confirm` and `cancel`.  Imagine passing in a `textbox` component.  Or a button styled incorrectly that takes up too much space and ruins the style of the rest of the modal. 
 It would render, but.... eugh.

And sure, human testing should catch those issues.  But if we need to rely on an actual human being, then we're susceptible to human error.  We all hate human error, right?

Instead, I would suggest making a prop named `buttonType`.  Use this prop as an enum to choose between whatever various button components you might wish to use.  Have a default.  e.g.

```
getButtonComponent() {
    switch( this.props.buttonType ) {
        case 'someType': return SomeType;
        case 'anotherType': return AnotherType;
        default: return DefaultType;
    }
}

render() {
    const ConfirmButton = this.getButtonComponent();
    const CancelButton = this.getButtonComponent();
    ...
```

Comment: Totally agree with your arguments, it's just that I'm trying to push the framework to see what it allows and what it doesn't :)